# jQuery.appear plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Please look at the following jsfiddle. It is a simple attempt at getting the jQuery.appear plugin to work. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/P7v8v/1/

The html is:

```
<div class = 'bar'>foo</div>
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
alert('foo bar');
$('.bar').appear();
$('.bar').on('appear', AlertMe);

function AlertMe() {
    alert("alert me");
}
```

The plugin can be downloaded at https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear#jqueryappear

Comment: Can you share where you downloaded this plugin?  Actually we need to know how this will work

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post with the link

Answer (score 1):

1) Appear triggers the event on scroll or resize (referencing your javascript fiddle on line 79)

```
$(window).scroll(on_check).resize(on_check);
```

2) for the code to work properly enclose it like this:

```
$(function(){
  ... your code goes here
 });
```

so it doesn't get executed before the libraries are loaded.

Hope this helps